# SVN - Skipped paths

Tags: svn

I received this message when I ran a SVN UP:

```
Skipped 'trunk/scripts/accountability_survey_report.php'
At revision 1585.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

I've been googling trying to figure out exactly what this means and how to resolve it. I tried deleting the file and then just svn up again, but I get the following:

```
Restored 'trunk/scripts/accountability_survey_report.php'
Skipped 'trunk/scripts/accountability_survey_report.php'
At revision 1585.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more info, trying to deduce what happened, I found this error message when doing a svn info FILENAME Tree conflict: local delete, incoming edit upon update and this one: Tree conflict: local obstruction, incoming add upon merge I found this post that fixed my problem: http://little418.com/2009/05/svn-local-obstruction-incoming-add-upon-merge.html

Answer (score 18):

I've seen the "Skipped paths" message when I've done a previous merge on the working copy and then reverted it. Then the file is added in the first merge but not deleted when you revert the working copy, the second merge tries to add the file but skips because the file already exists.

Comment: That's crazy dangerous. Just happened to me as well.

Comment: From that moment I only do merges over pristine working copies, just checked out from repository.

Comment: I just commit other directories around and delete (via SO) the parent of conflicting folder.

Answer (score 16):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797321/svnmerge-croaks-on-mysterious-conflict) might help you. The answer it gives is:

> Never, ever, forget to commit a run of
>   svnmerge.py before doing something
>   else. Combining a merge with other
>   edits is a recipe for a disaster, and
>   the disaster is what you see in the
>   question.

The [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/svn-book.html) also says:

> Whatever the case, the “skipped”
>   message means that the user is most
>   likely comparing the wrong two trees;
>   they're the classic sign of driver
>   error. When this happens, it's easy to
>   recursively revert all the changes
>   created by the merge (svn revert
>   --recursive), delete any unversioned files or directories left behind after
>   the revert, and re-run svn merge with
>   different arguments.

And then there's [this blog post](http://www.tecnotertulia.com/development/svn-skipped-pathtofile-is-misleading/96) that claims:

> I finally found a posting with
>   instructions on [how to merge in spite
>   of the “Skipped” error message](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@forrest.apache.org/msg02490.html)… so I
>   tried it, and it worked (in spite of
>   the misleading messages). The trick
>   really is to ignore the messages.
>
> Note that following the merge, files
>   that are in the source branch and not
>   in the destination branch need to be
>   svn added before they will end up in
>   the destination.

It seems the general consensus is that you need to do a proper merge of the file in question.

Comment: Thanks Franci, I guess I'm confused at how one would even do a incorrect merge (i'm trying to fix something someone else committed) ... but on to fixing it. So if I copy the current file off, do a 

svn revert --recursive filename

Then open that file and replace it with the saved file, that should fix it?

Comment: Yep, that ought to do.  Of course you'll have to review your changes later, as I suspect there's a conflict between what you touched and what's in the repo.

Comment: Some more info, trying to deduce what happened, I found this error message when doing a svn info FILENAME

Tree conflict: local delete, incoming edit upon update

and this one:

Tree conflict: local obstruction, incoming add upon merge

I found this post that fixed my problem:
http://little418.com/2009/05/svn-local-obstruction-incoming-add-upon-merge.html

Comment: that part about unversioned file bit me, having an unversioned file with the same name as a file added in the source of the merge forces a skip.

Answer (score 15):

I know this sounds simple but I'm going to post it just in case anyone else made the same mistake as me. Make certain you are updating from the correct directory. I got this error when I pressed svn up from the wrong directory.

Comment: Ha... I came here doing the same thing

Comment: Happened to me too. Extremely misleading error message.

Comment: I got skipped paths because I left the leading slash off the path: svn update path/to/directory rather than svn update /path/to/directory

Answer (score 2):

May be the file being skipped was already updated and reported conflicts?  If a file is already flagged as having conflicts, it will be skipped during Update.  Try resolving the conflicts and Update again and it should work without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution:

```
sudo svn delete --force accountability_survey_report.php
```

Now just to be sure run:

```
sudo svn commit --force accountability_survey_report.php
```

SVN will moan:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: 'trunk/scripts/accountability_survey_report.php' remains in conflict
```

Ignore the moaning, and run:

```
sudo svn update accountability_survey_report.php
A accountability_survey_report.php
Updated to revision ......
```

The above adds the latest copy of the file "accountability_survey_report.php" from the svn server to your local. Run svn update again and there will be no more svn complains about that file.

I will of-course backup the required copy of file first before deleting.

Comment: There is no "--force" param in the sudo svn commit

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, today. I did `svn info` on the file. It muttered something about `Tree conflict: local missing, incoming edit upon merge`. I am not sure how this could happen.

I fixed this by doing a `svn resolve --accept working` and `svn up` on the file, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It happened because the file has got conflict, just set this file as "resolved" and try the update again, this will become more easy with a graphic client svn.

Comment: This is actually a comment not an answer

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I got the Skipped Paths error when I accidentally ran the svn update command from a folder that didn't actually have anything checked out - I remembered after having come here looking for answers that it was only the child directories that I had checked stuff out in!

Dumb user error essentially in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you get something like this for example:

> Summary of conflicts: Skipped paths: 2

Just make sure you are in the correct directory.

I just did this and realized I hadn't navigated to the working directory.

Hope this helps!  :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I delete entery folder, then svn up and if needed svn switch.