# SVN update: 'skipped' message

Tags: svn, terminal

I'm trying to update by using

```
svn update --username myusername https://my.svn.address
```

However, I'm just getting a 'skipped' message?

Comment: maybe this not-so-old stackoverflow question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048662/svn-skipped-paths

Comment: Does svn status show that directory as a working copy?

Answer (score 39):

I guess you are getting this type of error.

```
[user@user myprojectdir]# svn up
Skipped '.'
```

do svn st from your project dir

```
[user@user myprojectdir]# svn st
svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy
```

it means you are not in your working dir.
You might have done a wrong checkout.

Correct way is this.

```
[user@user ~]# svn co http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/projectPRJ/trunk/ myprojectdir
[user@user ~]# cd myprojectdir
[user@user ~]# svn up
```

**Note: But if you messup with above order, svn up will not work for example.**

```
[user@user ~]# cd myprojectdir
[user@user myprojectdir]# svn co http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/projectPRJ/trunk/ 
[user@user myprojectdir]# svn up
```

you will get `Skipped '.'`

Answer (score 5):

If you're updating a working copy you don't need to provide the address of the remote repository. You just do `svn up` or `svn update`, the local working copy already contains the information about where the remote repository is located.

Comment: [user@user Mydir]#svn st
svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy

Comment: @shashaDenovo this results from you not having checked out a repository to the directory you run that command in, thus the directory is not a working copy. Try running something like `svn co http://public.repository.url/trunk/ .` first.

Answer (score 2):

Matti is correct. I would like to add to his point that we need to understand what is a working copy first. Then the difference between SVN export and SVN checkout.

If you ran the `svn export` command that wouldn't have created a working copy. Only `svn checkout` creates a working copy.

Answer (score 2):

I found the SVN client also may say "Skipped" during "svn up," if you use a path that is partly defined by a symbolic link. The workaround is either:

- cd to that directory, then say "svn up ."
- or define the path in a way of where the path is the cononical path

Answer (score 1):

This is what happened in my case : 
I had a conflict and accidentally committed my folder.
On checking the folder i had the **.mine** and **.r extension** files.I manually deleted the files and
got the svn working again

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem. Yeah I'm new to SVN. I had to update from the trunk directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the update directory from current dir
2. resolved the remove dir
3. revert the remove dir
4. svn up with removed dir
5. see results