# Subversion: Skipping folders when not in working directory

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu

We have our website files in various Subversion projects checked out on our Ubuntu 12.04 web server, a project for each site.

eg

- /var/www/site1/
- /var/www/site2/
- /var/www/site3/

Now, I can update from subversion if I am in the correct working directory e.g. I go

```
cd /var/www/site1
svn update filepath
```

Works fine

...but if I go

```
svn update /var/www/site1
```

I get the error:

```
Skipped 'site1'
```

Is it do with the fact that each subfolder of /var/www is a seperate Subversion Project checked out seperately? Or am I misunderstanding something entirely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the working copy directory and then do `svn up` inside that folder.

You can refer another question [SVN update: 'skipped' message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892281/svn-update-skipped-message)

Comment: That makes sense. I can't do it from outside the folder? I ask because my boss insists that's the way the code in our release script did it on the old servers. It's possible that they were checked out as one big root project somehow though