# how to delete .svn hidden files from terminal in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: svn

I have a problem in using svn repository. When i try to update my project in svn i m getting the following error

```
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~/brundelre3$ svn st
svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~/brundelre3$ svn up
Skipped '.'
```

I tried the things which explained about these error previously from these links:

- [Removing .svn files from all directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301203/removing-svn-files-from-all-directories)
- [find and remove hidden folders svn ubuntu linux command line](http://bookmarks.honewatson.com/2008/06/06/find-and-remove-hidden-folders-svn-ubuntu-linux-command-line/)
- [how remove all svn folders recursively](http://www.ubun2.com/question/348/how_remove_all_svn_folders_recursively)

but nothing solves my problem. I want to remove all the hidden files from my project.

Comment: What's the relation between `svn st` and removing all the hidden files from your project? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Or are you wandering why SVN doesn't work anymore after deleting the .svn directory? That's expected: SVN uses this directory to store everything it needs to work.

Comment: Do the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892281/svn-update-skipped-message help?

Answer (score 0):

.svn directory is in the root of your working directory. You need to only delete it from the root folder to unversion the files. You can checkout again at the same location and the svn will version all your files without downloading if there are no new updates.

Comment: It's worth to mention that Subversion prior to 1.7 places `.svn` dir in each folder of a working copy.