# post-commit hook failing with no output

Tags: svn, stderr, post-commit

So I'm getting the error `post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output.` after committing to the repository. The commit goes through fine, but the hook is obviously not working. The hook code is:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
TXN_NAME="$3"

/usr/bin/svn update --username user --password pass /var/www/clients/clientx/weby/web >&2

exit 1
```

I've tried changing the permission of `/var/www/clients/clientx/weby/web` to 775, but that doesn't work. It's an ISPConfig installation, so the user/group that runs the commit hook is `webz:clienty`, while the output folder's ownership is `webx:clienty`. I've also run the code without the `exit 1` and the `>&2`. I just need to be able to see what the problem is, and then I can fix it, but there is no output. I've read about `STDERR` and I think what I have should work.

I ran the same command, without the `exit 1` and `>&2`, from the command line and it worked, no problem.

I'm not sure why I can't get any output, or why the post-commit hook is returning an error.

Comment: Can you `su` to the webz user and run that command at the command line?

Comment: Ok, now it is saying `Skipped '/var/www/clients/clientx/weby/web'` and the it summarizes the conflicts, but still no error message.

Comment: I've been away from svn for too long to be much more help, but perhaps this link might give you more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048662/svn-skipped-paths -- Good luck!

Comment: I fixed the skipped path issue, but it still has not worked.

Comment: If you `su` to the webz user and run it at the command line, are you still getting errors? If so, just keep doing that until you track down all the bugs and get them fixed.

Comment: no when I su to the webz user it works now...

Comment: Debian 8, I tried changing `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107753/discussion-between-marknfi-and-ashraj98).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that the problem was that the post-commit hook was not even running. I ran the whole post-commit hook from the terminal itself, and [got this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter). All I needed to do was make the file Unix executable by using `vim` and running the command `:set fileformat=unix`. This effectively solved the issue.