# jenkins is skipping a line(command) of batch file

Tags: batch-file, svn, jenkins, cmd

So, I wrote a simple batch file which will update a directory lets say `../../sqlscripts` and copied `svn.exe` to the directory where my `.bat` file is, so that I can call `svn update` in that batch files to update a particular folder. Here is the content of the batch file

```
svn update ../../sqlscripts
```

when I am executing this batch script from CMD it is getting executed and updating the folder `../../sqlscripts`. But the issue comes when I am executing the batch script from jenkins. Folder `../../sqlscripts` is not getting updated and I am having this log in jenkins

```
Skipped '..\..\sqlscripts'
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

I am not able to figure out what the issue is, rest of the line of the batch files are being executed as expected.

Comment: Did u check the working directory is correct? (CD - current directory)

Comment: @marsze directory is correct, it is working fine if I am executing through CMD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048662/svn-skipped-paths

Comment: that answer is not helping in this case  @marsze

Comment: Since your batch only contains one single line with a relative path it heavily depends on where and from where u execute it. Try a full path just for fun to see if that works. If it does, you know where to start looking.

Comment: I got it, I just changed the line svn update `../../sqlscripts` to absolute path `svn update D:\QAENVs\R16.4\sqlscripts` and its working fine. The conscusion whenever you are trying to execute the batch file from jenkins always use absolute paths otherwise its not going to work.

Comment: ...or set the working directory properly. E.g. add `cd "%~dp0"` at the beginning of the batch. This will set the working directory to the one the batch resides in.

Comment: I am glad you found an answer. I am not sure it is advisable to copy svn.exe to another directory. Can it run from where it was installed? Must you keep it out of the PATH?

Comment: @Liturgist same thought came to my mind also, but I didn't find any way to update a dir in batch script that why I used this work around. Its not good practice I think.

Comment: If the directory containing `svn.exe` is in the PATH variable, then you do not need to put it into the current directory. Since you know a fully qualified path to copy `svn.exe` from, you could use that if the directory cannot be in the PATH variable.